# how can show profile User in html django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

i create user auth and make model profile user with signals to create profile like User

but i want show user profile in template

---- model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

# Create your models here.
class profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    music = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    skils = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    search = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    posts = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    boi = models.TextField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile-img")

    def __str__(self):
        #return self.user or 'User'
        return str(self.id)

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = profile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

---- path

```
path('profile/<int:id>', views.profile, name="profile")
```

----- views

```
def profile(request, id):
    ff = profile.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {'ff' : ff}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

views not work i dont know  the problem

in html...

{% url 'profile' profile.id %}

how can show profile User in html django

Comment: You are passing the profile object into the context as `ff`. In your template, you can do `{{ ff.music }}` for example. Can you ask in a more clear way what exactly your problem is, or what you are trying to do? "views not work" followed by a snippet of a url doesn't explain what you mean by "show profile user".

Answer (score 0):

If you want User can show his Profile, you need to `get` the Profile object using the current user instance instead of profile `id` like this...

#### views.py

```py
def profile(request):
    ff = profile.objects.get(user=request.user) # This query object give logged in user profile
    context = {'ff' : ff}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

Profile url path become like this

#### urls.py

```
path('profile/', views.profile, name="profile")
```

Html url becomes like this

```
{% url 'profile' %}
```

##### NOTE - No need pass id of profile because here we get profile of current user which is logged in